# generic gdi+ error when creating icons

Tags: vb.net, memory-leaks, icons, gdi+, system.drawing

I'm at my wits end with this one. I have a function that returns an icon. My issue is that while the application is running and the function is being used I can watch my applications memory usage climb. After a few minutes I will get a "A generic error occurred in GDI+" Which causes my application to crash.
I've gone through the forums and found suggestions but nothing I've tried seems to resolve the issue. Adding the .dispose() at the end of the function extended the length of time before this happens but did not stop it.
Here is the code which has my issue:

```
Private Function drawIcon(ByVal frameColor As Color, ByVal numColor As Color, ByVal capColor As Color, ByVal scrColor As Color)
    Dim ti As Icon
    Dim bmp As New Bitmap(16, 16)
    Dim bmpgraphics As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
    Using bmpgraphics
        Dim framePen As New Pen(frameColor)
        Dim numBrush As New SolidBrush(numColor)
        Dim capBrush As New SolidBrush(capColor)
        Dim scrBrush As New SolidBrush(scrColor)
        Dim strip As Integer = 64 / 3
        'outside
        Dim numFrame As Rectangle = New Rectangle(0, 0, strip, 16 - 1)
        Dim capFrame As Rectangle = New Rectangle(strip, 0, strip, 16 - 1)
        Dim scrFrame As Rectangle = New Rectangle(strip * 2, 0, strip, 16 - 1)
        ' inside
        Dim numInside As Drawing.Rectangle = New Rectangle(1, 1, strip - 1, 16 - 2)
        Dim capInside As Drawing.Rectangle = New Rectangle(strip + 1, 1, strip - 1, 16 - 2)
        Dim scrInside As Drawing.Rectangle = New Rectangle(strip * 2 + 1, 1, strip - 1, 16 - 2)
        ' do the drawing
        With bmpgraphics
            .DrawRectangle(framePen, numFrame)
            .DrawRectangle(framePen, capFrame)
            .DrawRectangle(framePen, scrFrame)
            .FillRectangle(numBrush, numInside)
            .FillRectangle(capBrush, capInside)
            .FillRectangle(scrBrush, scrInside)
        End With
        'Dim tmpBmp As New Bitmap(bmp)
        'ti = Drawing.Icon.FromHandle(tmpBmp.GetHicon)
        'tmpBmp.Dispose()
        ti = Drawing.Icon.FromHandle(bmp.GetHicon)
    End Using
    bmp.Dispose()
    bmpgraphics.Dispose()
    Return ti
End Function
```

Comment: Not part of the problem, but turn on Option Strict.  Those pends and brushes are resources which need to be disposed (or `Using`d) the Icon return is also a resource.  When the subscriber code is done with it, it needs to be disposed as well.

Comment: Just had a similar error on a website today that has charts--it's been running for months and never had a problem.  Did an iisreset and it's working again.  Not sure yet if it was just a temporary hiccup by IIS or if I need to fix something, but thought I'd mention it in case it's helpful.

Comment: Thanks Guys. I think I have it licked now. I stumbled across a fix on another site.

Answer (score 0):

Found this fix on another site. Didn't think to bookmark and can't seem to dig it up out of history. Once I added the DestroyIcon function I've had my program up and running for more than 8 hours memory usage goes up and then

```
    Private Declare Auto Function DestroyIcon Lib "user32" (ByVal hIcon As IntPtr) As Boolean

    Private Function drawIcon(ByVal frameColor As Color, ByVal numColor As Color, ByVal capColor As Color, ByVal scrColor As Color)
    Dim bmp As New Bitmap(16, 16)
    Dim bmpgraphics As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
    Using bmpgraphics ' As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(pb.Image)
        Dim ti As Icon
        Dim framePen As New Pen(frameColor)
        Dim numBrush As New SolidBrush(numColor)
        Dim capBrush As New SolidBrush(capColor)
        Dim scrBrush As New SolidBrush(scrColor)
        Dim strip As Integer = 64 / 3
        'outside
        Dim numFrame As Rectangle = New Rectangle(0, 0, strip, 16 - 1)
        Dim capFrame As Rectangle = New Rectangle(strip, 0, strip, 16 - 1)
        Dim scrFrame As Rectangle = New Rectangle(strip * 2, 0, strip, 16 - 1)
        ' inside
        Dim numInside As Drawing.Rectangle = New Rectangle(1, 1, strip - 1, 16 - 2)
        Dim capInside As Drawing.Rectangle = New Rectangle(strip + 1, 1, strip - 1, 16 - 2)
        Dim scrInside As Drawing.Rectangle = New Rectangle(strip * 2 + 1, 1, strip - 1, 16 - 2)
        ' do the drawing
        With bmpgraphics
            .DrawRectangle(framePen, numFrame)
            .DrawRectangle(framePen, capFrame)
            .DrawRectangle(framePen, scrFrame)
            .FillRectangle(numBrush, numInside)
            .FillRectangle(capBrush, capInside)
            .FillRectangle(scrBrush, scrInside)
        End With
        'Dim tmpBmp As New Bitmap(bmp)
        'ti = Drawing.Icon.FromHandle(tmpBmp.GetHicon)
        'tmpBmp.Dispose()
        'ti = Drawing.Icon.FromHandle(bmp.GetHicon)

        Dim hicon As IntPtr = bmp.GetHicon()
        Dim bitmapIcon As Icon = Icon.FromHandle(hicon)
        DestroyIcon(bitmapIcon.Handle)
        Return bitmapIcon
    End Using
    bmp.Dispose()
    bmpgraphics.Dispose()
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way could be building an array of Icons once, at program startup, then get the needed icon from there instead of converting it every time from bitmap.

```
Module MyModule
    Public IconList16() As Icon

    Sub BuildIconList(SourceImgList as ImageList)
        ' Builds up Icon List from provided ImageList
        Dim q As Int16
        Dim bmp As Bitmap = Nothing

        ReDim IconList16(MainForm.Icons16.Images.Count - 1)
        For q = 0 To UBound(IconList16)
            bmp = SourceImgList.Images(q)
            IconList16(q) = Icon.FromHandle(bmp.GetHicon)
        Next
        bmp.Dispose()

    End Sub

    (...)

    Sub AnySub()
        Dim IconID as Integer

        ' Initialize IconList16
        Call BuildIconList(Form1.ImageList1)                
        (...)
            (do stuff)
        (...)
        IconID = [**ChosenValue**]                      ' Just make sure IconID is set to a value which is in IconList16 bounds...
        AnySuitableObject.Icon = Iconlist16(IconID)     ' AnySuitableObject: any object, having .Icon property, of course.

End Sub
```

End Module